# How can I retrieve business listing with their geocodes for a specific region?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I have a form with a search box.
User can enter any geographic location like country, region, city, etc.
With this, I want to retrieve business listing alog with with thier geographic coordiantes.
I will display this listing in a defined manner. If your clicks on a business, I'll show that location in the google earth browser plugin.

Please guide me how I can retrieve that listing?

Answer (score 1):

The Geocoder doesn't return business listings, for that you'll need to use the AJAX Local Search API. Docs here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html